# Overlaying anchor tag on a video

Tags: html, angular, video

I'm using the angular4 framework to overlay a set of clickable areas on a video using html tags.

The basic idea is when a video is played predefined areas in the video, will be highlighted using an anchor tag. Information such as height, width and seconds are given to draw the area on top of the video.

I'd like to know how this could be achieved using [videoangular2](https://github.com/videogular/videogular2) or any other method recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `videoangular2` will not be able to help here as it's just a video player to display the video. In order to add a cliackable area, I would suggest positioning an anchor absolutely on top of the video player and using the HTML5/videoangular2 events and API to hide/show related ones. Hope that helps.

Comment: Currently working on this as a solution. Working alright so far. Only problem I see is with responsiveness and when you go full-screen. But it does the job.

Comment: I would appreciate if you tick the answer ;)

Comment: As soon as I implement it!